# Bit Shifting in SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I have a column `id` in my table `C_Log` to which I want to apply a bit shift of 32bits towards the right while integrating this task with the rest of the SELECT query!

After applying bit shifting on id `6670501767432108171` I should get this timestamp number `1553097220` (Both Decimal).

Comment: Are you using MySQL, Sybase or MS SQL Server?

Comment: @jarlh Probably... :P  (Sorry, just joking. It's friday afternoon.)

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you can directly perform a right shift:

```
SELECT ..., (id >> 32) AS ts, ... FROM C_log ...
```

SQL Server doesn't have bit shifts, so you need to do an equivalent division and take the `FLOOR`:

```
SELECT ..., (id / 4294967296) AS ts, ... FROM C_log ...
```